# Using logical or in seeInDatabase

Tags: php, laravel, testing, codeception

How can I implement a logic 'or' operator in Codeception's seeInDatabase method?.

For example: the methods syntax is

```
seeInDatabase('table', array('column1' => 'value1', 'column2' => 'value2'));
```

Which generates this query

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table`
WHERE `column1` = 'value1'
    AND `column2` = 'value2'
```

How can I generate the following query?

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table`
WHERE `column1` = 'value1'
    AND (
            `column2` = 'value2'
            OR `column2` = 'value3'
        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this-

```
$this->seeInDatabase('table', function($query)
{
    $query->where('column1', 'value1')->where('column2', 'value2')->orWhere('column2','value3');
});
```

Or You can do this split into some simple steps.
First get the records-

```
$model = Model::where('column1', 'value1')->where('column2','value2')->orWhere('column2','value3')->first();
```

then test-

```
$this->assertNotNull($model);
```

For better understanding, you can [see](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/9292) this.